# Online Admissions System

Tags: php, mysql, relationships

I am working on Online Admissions System in mysql and php.

I need to save applicant's personal as well as academic details. So far I have created one table to save personal details with Applicant Id (auto increment) as a Primary Key. But for academic details I am bit confused. The fields required for academic details are:

> ```
> Degree Level (like Master, Bachelor, high school);
> Roll No;
> Subjects; 
> Grade;
> Institution;
> Percentage;
> Degree image (image field to save scanned copies of transcripts).
> ```

I do not know how to relate these two tables. Would uploading image files (scanned copies of transcripts) affect the database performance?

Comment: general rule: never store files in the database. there's very few usage cases that justify it, and far too many gotchas/problems to make those few cases worthwhile.

Comment: don't store images in your database, store a reference to them. you should also be very careful with storing personal info, it should always be encrypted.

Comment: Put ApplicantID in the Academic Details table as a foreign key.

Comment: Those are the fields a user could see. You need an extra field to relate both tables. A field in the academic details should point to the primary key of the table holding aplicant data. But I think more than this hint, you really need a basic course about databases.

Answer (score 0):

You would have 2 tables

Applicants

```
Id | Name | Address | etc, etc
```

AcademicDetails

```
Id | ApplicantId | Degree | RollNo | DegreeImageUrl | etc, etc
```

To list all applicants

```
SELECT * FROM Applicants
```

To search for a specific Applicant by Name.

```
SELECT * FROM Applicants WHERE name = 'Tom Jones'
```

To select an Applicant Id=1 and all their Academic details use a join

```
SELECT * FROM Applicants JOIN AcademicDetails ON AcademicDetails.ApplicantId=Applicants.Id
 WHERE Applicants.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate table with a structure similar to the following which would hold all  of the various types of images you would need:

```
documents
--------------------
| id, INT AUTOINCREMENT
| applicant_id, INT
| type, VARCHAR(255)
| url, VARCHAR(255)
--------------------
```

The `applicant_id` would refer to the applicant to whom the documentation pertains to. The `type` field could be one of `degree` or `transcript` or whatever else type of documentation you support. And finally the `url` field would contain the location to the image. Preferably, you should have a PHP form that uploads images to a directory on your server and then adds a record to the `documents` table relating to what the user just uploaded.